# How do I check the type of a variable inside an `if` statement

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a problem in this area

```
if (components[i] == **TextOptionType**) {
```

I'm self-debugging a plug-in for a program called obsidian.

~ObsidianDevLibrary.ts is located at Importing ~type.ts.

There is a problem in referring to TextOptionType as a value.

How can I solve this?

type.ts

```
export type TextOptionType = {
    [propName: string] : any,
    key: string,
    placeholder?: string,
    autoSave?: boolean,
    value?: boolean,
    onChange?: onChangeType,
}
```

ObsidianDevLibrary.ts

```
for (let i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    if (components[i] == TextOptionType) {
        componentsToReturn.push(this.addText(setting, components[i]))
    }
}
```

Maybe comparing TextOptionType with if is wrong grammar, but I don't know the right way.

It may be intended to verify that the data entering the component is formatted

https://github.com/KjellConnelly/obsidian-dev-tools

Comment: Use a type-predicate (also known as a "type-guard"): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: What is the type of `components`?

Answer (score 1):

Define [a type-predicate `function` that checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for known members of `TextOptionType`, like so:

```js
function isTextOptionType( x: unknown ): x is TextOptionType {

    const whatIf = x as TextOptionType;
    return (
        ( typeof whatIf === 'object' && whatIf !== null )
        &&
        ( typeof whatIf.key === 'string' )
        &&
        ( typeof whatIf.placeholder === 'string' || typeof whatIf.placeholder === 'undefined' )
        &&
        ( typeof whatIf.autoSave === 'boolean' || typeof whatIf.autoSave === 'undefined' )
        &&
        ( typeof whatIf.value === 'boolean' || typeof whatIf.value === 'undefined' )
        &&
        ( typeof whatIf.onChange === 'function' || typeof whatIf.onChange === 'undefined' )
    );
}
```

Used like so:

```js
for( const c of components ) {
    if( isTextOptionType( c ) ) {
        componentsToReturn.push( this.addText( setting, c ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. We solved the problem.
I solved the problem, but when I checked, the development was stopped, so nothing was working inside. Ha ha.